# Fixed footer in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm trying out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and I was wondering, how I can fix the footer on the bottom without having it disappear from the page if the content is scrolled?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

To get a footer that sticks to the bottom of your viewport, give it a fixed position like this:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Bootstrap includes this CSS in the Navbar > Placement section with the class `fixed-bottom`. Just add this class to your footer element:

```
<footer class="fixed-bottom">
```

Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom

Comment: This and @Daniel-Tero's comment did it for me.

Comment: If a page has scrolling, it is not working properly.

Comment: `fixed-bottom` didn't do what I was expecting, I did instead `static-bottom` to respect the page content height.

Comment: If the body of the page is tall enough to have scrolling content, that the body overlaps the footer. How can I prevent this overlapping?

Comment: give the footer a non-transparent background-color and a border-top, so the footer will be always displayed, and you can scroll far enough, so all the content will appear above your footer

Answer (score 93):

Add this:

```html
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21604189

**EDIT:** class `navbar-fixed-bottom` has been changed to `fixed-bottom` as of Bootstrap v4-alpha.6.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#placement

Answer (score 27):

Add [fixed-bottom](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#fixed-bottom):

```
<div class="footer fixed-bottom">
```

Comment: Works with these examples: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/footers/

Answer (score 4):

Another solution :

You can use "min-height: 80vh;".

This allows you to set the minimum height, using the viewport height.

Example with bootstrap :

```
<style>
main {
   min-height: 80vh;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -60px;
}
</style>

<main class="container">
    <!-- Your page content here... -->
</main>
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <!-- Your page footer here... -->
</footer>
```

| Compatibility : |
| --- |
| Chrome 31+ / FireFox 31+ / Safari 7+ / Internet Expl. 9+ / Opera 29+ |

More information :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 3):

Add `z-index:-9999;` to this method, or it will cover your top bar if you have `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by wrapping the page contents in a div with the following id styling applied:

```
<style>
#wrap {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -60px;
}
</style>

<div id="wrap">
    <!-- Your page content here... -->
</div>
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

You might want to check that example:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: That's for sticky footer, not fixed footer :/

Comment: @aaronz what's the difference?

Comment: @ArsenIbragimov Sticky footer gets pushed down to the end of the page if the content is taller than the view. Fixed footer is always visible at the bottom of the view.