# Bootstrap 3 fixed footer is breaking my mobile site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I'm using a fixed footer on my webpage.

On mobile, it is fixing to the bottom of the page and covering other content.

How can I change it so that the footer is fixed only on large/desktop screens?

Comment: use media query for that

Comment: this is the refrense `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile` and for mobile and tablet , change `position` attribute `fixed` to `relative` of `.navbar-fixed-bottom` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed footer in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330611/fixed-footer-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

Use `media query` css for the solution.

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { .navbar-fixed-bottom{position:relative !important;} }
@media (min-width:480px)  { .navbar-fixed-bottom{position:relative !important;} }
@media (min-width:600px)  { .navbar-fixed-bottom{position:relative !important;} }
```

Hope this answer helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about bootstrap 3 breakpoints [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Small screens are usually smaller than `768px`, so if you don't want the footer fixed on small screens. you can change the position of the footer in the small screens using the media queries.

```css
/*for mobile phones and tablets (both)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: static !important;
  }
}

/* for mobile phones only*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

Or you can see one more solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592968/bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-media-queries) for the same.

You can check the mobile view of the website the developer tools the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Or second solution is to add padding for container on mobiles:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .my_container{

      padding-bottom: 100px !important; //example

    }
}
```

Padding must have at least footer height + some px for good looking.