# Bootstrap 4 aligning row to the bottom of a container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I align a bootstrap row to the bottom of a container?

Like this:
[image: Like this]

**HTML**

```
<main class="bd-masthead container-fluid" id="" role="main" style="padding-top:5rem;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 class="text-light">
        LukeBank
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(/img/frontpage.bg.jpg); 
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover; 
}

.otherpart {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;  
}
```

I tried to use `.align-bottom`, but it didn't work.

Comment: do you want to attach at bottom of the currently visible **View Port** of the screen or at the bottom of the container?

Comment: The Container...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do this with

```css
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

But it's not a proper way to do this. You can add near to your ***col*** class

> align-self-center

Answer (score 19):

For bootstrap 4, you can use the shorthand classes and set `mt-auto`, which will have the effect of aligning your element to the bottom of the container.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: correct answer.  might also want to use row-eq-height on the row.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using bootstrap 4, you can use the class - fixed-bottom.

Check :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom

[Fixed footer in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330611/fixed-footer-in-bootstrap)

Comment: This is the correct answer, probably due to the progression of time and updates to the framework.

Comment: This is the best answer for bootstrap 4 or higher. works as a charm

Answer (score 4):

Try to add *align-self-end* class to the div with *col* class

```html
<div class="col align-self-center">
```

Answer (score 3):

To align to bottom you could try with flexbox:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
```

or if you just have one element

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
```