# How to have a footer in the bottom of the page on any case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I Want to have a fixed footer at the bottom of an HTML page, even in XS an SM sizes.

When i make it relative, it depends of what is displayed, and I want it fixed at the bottom.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed footer in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330611/fixed-footer-in-bootstrap)

Comment: I find this article really helpful. https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/
The firsrt image exactly shows your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following style:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

You'll of course have to adjust it to your specific case. If you had a code example I could give you something more specific.

Comment: Yes, actually when I passed to XS an SM, The footer is at the bottom, but at the bottom of the body. So my footer stands at the middle of my page...

Comment: @jozinho22 I hadn't seen this, but it probably was an issue related to `html` and `body` height definitions. Although those don't really affect `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you get a sticky footer

```
body{
min-height: 100vh;
flex-direction: column;  
}

footer{
  margin-top:auto;
}
```