# bootstrap place footer at bottom if content has smaller height then window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to place the footer at bottom of the window if the content of window has no scrollbars otherwise put the footer at the end of content
here is my html code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="con"></div>
    <div class="footer">Copyright msg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you are looking for is known as a 'sticky footer', I believe -- where the footer will always appear pinned to the bottom of the page, even if the content is very short? You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer).