# Place a footer with bootstrap in Layout-Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap framework and ASP.Net MVC 5. I want a footer on the bottom left of the screen. Reading a few tutorials and samples I ended up with this code in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
 <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted"><span>Version <a href="/ReleaseNotes.html">1.1.0.0</a></span></p>
    </div>
 </footer>
```

This shows a footer on the left bottom side of my page. But it is not fixed. If the website contains no content, the footer is shown on the top of the page.

How to set a fix location for the footer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this as on the getbootstrap.com: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcbpbt5h/

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
 #wrap {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
   margin: 0 auto -60px;
 }

 #push,
 #footer {
   height: 60px;
 }

#footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="container">content</div>
    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
 <footer id="footer">
 <div class="container">
     footer
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Great, I found this sample on my own but thought the relevant CSS classes are already included in bootstrap. Works now, thx.