# How to set a bootstrap 3 container to 100% of browser height with a sticky footer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Like the title says, how do I set a bootstrap 3 container (wrapper) to 100% of the height of a browser window using a sticky footer?

[BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/Hs9IiwpiQk)

UPDATE:

the sticky footer works fine, it's the first `'<div class="container">'` that I need to be 100% height

Comment: possibly previously answered? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap+sticky+footer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer)

Comment: I updated my question - maybe it wasn't clear enough. the sticky footer is fine ~ it's the container I need 100% height.

Comment: This is good working example: http://www.bootply.com/panchroma/70755

Comment: This is not a previously answered question, the issue isn't with the footer, its with the container div needing to be 100% height.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the page height to 100% and then put the footer at the bottom with a margin of it's height.

Like done here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Start by adding this to your css:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

And for the footer add this

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: This addresses the sticky footer - which works, the question was about setting a container's height, if you take a look at the bootply example, it's the first container that I need to be 100% height.