# Bootstrap Anchor Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if some one can help me with the footer not sticking to the bottom on all pages.  I am using bootstrap and have an issue where sometimes it's at the bottom but on other pages it is not working correctly.  Mobile (emulation doesn't seem to show) on an actual device cuts off some of the page to not show the full content.

http://gerddagne.com/wp/ - This page the footer is still not at the bottom but when you view on mobile the footer cuts off some of the inline menu...

http://gerddagne.com/wp/biography/ - Footer snaps up to the text...

I can't find what guide I used but it seems my CSS is lacking lately so I can't figure out what is causing the issue, anyone from this awesome community able to shed light on why my footer is not sticking to the bottom?

Comment: This post might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer

Comment: Please include some code in your question, and don't just link to your live website. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @joydesigner thank you that link was exactly what I needed, I implemented that and it worked flawlessly.  I can't accept his answer though...

Answer (score 0):

try this : add this in your css:

```
#f{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```