# how to have a footer stay at bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so I created a wireframe to elaborate on the situation: https://wireframe.cc/cQsG8D

Basically I have a page (in HAML if that makes any difference) ... in which there is a scrollable viewport whose height is set to 360px currently.

And there is a text message box underneath it ... I've tried everything to get that text message box go down to the bottom of the page, including doing the same things that twitter bootstrap does in their example: [getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

I want to be able to get rid of the height requirement of the viewport, if that's possible and to get the text message box stay at the bottom of the page.

Any advice, please? I've been noodling on this pretty much the whole day yesterday, and now, I'm crazy sick of it ...

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer)

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute positioning for the footer.

```
.bottom-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

If you wanted it to be sticky, replace `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties to your `textbox`

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/u94571a7/)**

```
#txtBottom
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
```