# How to make footer go to bottom when there isn't enough content on page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7

I want the footer to always be aligned at the very bottom of the browser window.

I do **not** want to use the "sticky footer" because I don't want it to overlay any of my content.

When the page has enough content it looks ok, but when it doesn't it just appears randomly across the screen.

Example of markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <h1>My page</h1>
      <p>Page content here</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><p>Footer content here</p></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

If there's plenty of content in the body of the page it's ok. But for short pages it's not.

I'm using the default nav bar at it's default height

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">

</nav>
```

I've looked for solutions on this but none seem to work. Can't understand why Bootstrap have made this so complex to do such a simple task. Not everyone wants a sticky footer!

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer

Comment: @MoneerKamal that's for the sticky footer, which is what I don't want to use.

Comment: @AudreyRoberts what's wrong with sticky footer? [bootstraps example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Comment: I think you do want the "sticky footer" example, but the name "sticky footer" is mis-leading. It doesn't overlay the content and pushes down when the content is longer than the viewport: http://www.bootply.com/4Tt79fRBDF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about IE < 10 you can use flex.
It's really simple, but as mentioned it's only for "modern" browsers.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- main content goes here -->
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm accepting it as the answer because it works, and solves my problem. If you have a solution which works in all browsers and care to explain the logic of how it works, I'll change the accepted answer. If not, this just works and is fine for my needs.

Comment: My comment wasn't about if it worked or not, it was about the fact that SO frowns on *link-only-answers* because if the link dies, then so does this answer.  He has updated the answer with the example, which means future users don't have to work about a link dying or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you make body height as 100% and removed the footer height

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

.content {
        height: calc(100vh - 150px);
        height: -o-calc(100vh - 150px); /* opera */
        height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 150px); /* google, safari */
        height: -moz-calc(100vh - 150px); /* firefox */
    }

.content {
    background-color:red;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;

}

.footer{
  background-color:green;
  height:150px;
}
```

check out my code on   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adratarek/0k398s6r/)

try to change

```
>   min-height: 500px;
```

to

```
> min-height: 200px;
```

IN

```
> ".content"
```

to see the difference