# Bootstrap sticky footer has problems with small width page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a footer that stays below the page content and sticks to the bottom of the page. I've tried applying [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer) to my page, but it causes the footer to stick to the bottom and overlap the page content (if the page is too short).

I'm currently using the css:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 348px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 348px;
}
```

and the html: (simplified)

```
<body>
   <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container"
    page content
    </div>
  </div>
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <!-- Footer-->
</footer>
</body>
```

and the footer is now sticking to the bottom, but when the page is very narrow, you can see through to the background instead of the footer background covering it.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWe5.png)

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to a 'short' page? Ah, it also doesn't work properly when the page isn't very short.

Comment: Your page seems fine? where is the sticky footer in the link you specified? More over i wouldnt recommend making a 348px tall footer `sticky` !!

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph The black footer at the bottom. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWe5.png When the page is narrow this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have used `jQuery`. Along with removing the height from `footer`, a simple `resize()` event can decide the correct `margin-bottom`.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var xHeight = $('.footer').height();
    $('body').css('margin-bottom',xHeight + 'px');
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This gets the job done. Kinda disappointing that jQuery is needed.

Comment: Or else use media queries as @sneha suggested !! But you will have to work on which screen size needs how much `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the height. Just remove the height from `footer` then it will be fine.

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 348px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

<!----html---->
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">page content</div>
    </div>
   <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom"></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: This one is perfect @huhn

Comment: Thanks. However, now when the page is narrow the footer begins to overlap the page content, hiding it. http://i.imgur.com/St43mlr.png

Comment: write media query for all screen then chnage the value of wrapper class.          example                                                                                          .wrapper {
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}

Comment: @sneha then the OP would have to sit and resize the browser and find all the `margin-bottom` values for all screen sizes `:)`

Comment: Thats why I am saying write media query for mobile ,tablet and desktop.