# How to make a fixed footer?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
  <section>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="upper-div">
    <img src="images/pic.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="lower-div">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil sequi possimus alias numquam sunt perspiciatis sint, molestiae aperiam, rerum, deleniti quos. Repellat tenetur, repudiandae quae odit obcaecati libero magnam vero.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A error libero impedit sequi quae blanditiis assumenda, dolores beatae mollitia quas dolor voluptatibus saepe voluptate quod velit id eaque nostrum architecto.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A error libero impedit sequi quae blanditiis assumenda, dolores beatae mollitia quas dolor voluptatibus saepe voluptate quod velit id eaque nostrum architecto.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: How do I pull the footer section to the bottom of the screen??]

```
.main-wrapper{
padding:15px;
}

.header,
.footer{
     text-align: center;
}

.header p,
.footer p{
    padding:10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.content{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.content-card{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

I've tried giving the fixed position to the footer div and bottom 0 but then it goes out of the div and negates the padding of the outer main-wrapper. How do i fix it so i dont have to give specific height to the content wrapper and the height of the content div adapts to the device and the footer is fixed in the bottom.?

Comment: can you clarify your question please. u want the footer to remain in its parent div and respect the padding of its parent but to also be fixed at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Can you include the CSS you're using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966140/twitter-bootstrap-3-sticky-footer)

Comment: you'll need to fill your viewport. Make `html, body, otherContainers {height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reduce the width of the footer to make it similar to your header.

```css
.main-wrapper{
padding:15px;
}

.header,
.footer{
     text-align: center;
}

.header p,
.footer p{
    padding:10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.content{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.content-card{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 93%;
}
```

```html
 <section>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="upper-div">
    <img src="images/pic.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="lower-div">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil sequi possimus alias numquam sunt perspiciatis sint, molestiae aperiam, rerum, deleniti quos. Repellat tenetur, repudiandae quae odit obcaecati libero magnam vero.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A error libero impedit sequi quae blanditiis assumenda, dolores beatae mollitia quas dolor voluptatibus saepe voluptate quod velit id eaque nostrum architecto.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A error libero impedit sequi quae blanditiis assumenda, dolores beatae mollitia quas dolor voluptatibus saepe voluptate quod velit id eaque nostrum architecto.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you help me with the height of the content div !? I want the scroll to show when the items in that div touches the footer div, so i don't want to give specific height to the content div.

Comment: use max-height and overflow:auto in your content class. This must work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `section` tag was not completed. Also made changes in css. Here is the working solution.

```css
.main-wrapper{
padding:15px;
}

.header,
.footer{
     text-align: center;
}

.header p,
.footer p{
    padding:10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.content{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.content-card{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <section>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="upper-div">
    <img src="images/pic.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="lower-div">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil sequi possimus alias numquam sunt perspiciatis sint, molestiae aperiam, rerum, deleniti quos. Repellat tenetur, repudiandae quae odit obcaecati libero magnam vero.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A error libero impedit sequi quae blanditiis assumenda, dolores beatae mollitia quas dolor voluptatibus saepe voluptate quod velit id eaque nostrum architecto.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A error libero impedit sequi quae blanditiis assumenda, dolores beatae mollitia quas dolor voluptatibus saepe voluptate quod velit id eaque nostrum architecto.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```